# What is the "stringWithContentsOfURL" replacement for objective C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I found a tutorial on the net that uses the stringWithContentsOfURL command that is now deprecated as of iPhone OS 3.0. However I can't find out what I'm meant to use instead, and how to implement it.

Below is the code surrounding the stringWithContentsOfURL line in case you need it for reference.

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=%@&output=csv", 
     [addressField.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSString *locationString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
NSArray *listItems = [locationString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It has been replaced with `stringWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error:` or `stringWithContentsOfURL:usedEncoding:error:`.

Answer (score 82):

Thanks Greg, but for all those other beginners here is an example

```
NSError* error = nil;
NSString* text = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:TheUrl encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error];
if( text )
{
    NSLog(@"Text=%@", text);
}
else 
{
    NSLog(@"Error = %@", error);
}
```

Comment: HI, if I am not wrong _text_ will not be _FALSE_ or _NIL_ even if your server returns an internal error or anything similar? This error is more about error in encoding?
Apple is really rigorous on handling connection errors so my question is what's the use of _stringWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error:_ method when you can't deal the reall "not available" errors? thanks. L

Comment: @luigi7up : I guess you're right. nil is returned if there is an error that cause no return data being caught (server connection error, encoding error). If a 404 error happens, some text is returned (the 404 error page), and error should contain the error. I'm not sure that is what happens with a sync connection like this one, but this is the behaviour of an async connection.

Comment: Does this not bring up incompatible pointer type warnings for anyone else? Is it just me?

Answer (score 1):

Below code will remove your warning message........any question please let mo know.

```
- (void) connectedToNetwork 
{
    BOOL aflag = ([NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.co.in/"] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:nil]!=NULL)?YES:NO; 
    if (!aflag) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"Sorry!....You are not connected to network " 
                              delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Exit" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anything more than trivial, I recommend ASIHTTPRequest:

http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/