# Function deprecated in ios 4

Tags: iphone, ios4

Hi all i update to ios 4 but in my app i use :

```
NSString *connected = [NSString string withContentofURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myurl.com/myFile]];
```

but now i get the following :

```
StringWithContentsofURL is deprecated !
```

I use this to test if connection is available.

What can i do ??

thanks

Comment: Check this Stack question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039203/what-is-the-stringwithcontentsofurl-replacement-for-objective-c

Answer (score 3):

As of iPhone OS2 (so this is not new) the

`[NSString withContentsOfURL: (NSURL*) url]`

method has been replaced with

[`+ (id)stringWithContentsOfURL: (NSURL *)url encoding: (NSStringEncoding)enc error: (NSError **)error`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSString/stringWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error:)

Here's an example using the new signature:

```
NSError* error = nil;
NSURL* url = [NSURL urlWithString: @"www.google.com"];
NSString* stringForUrlPath = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL: url 
                                                      encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding 
                                                         error: &error];
```

See [this](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-BAJJAICE) for your options for NSStringEncoding.

Comment: What kind of websites are you visiting?  Most likely NSUTF8StringEncoding should serve you just fine.

Answer (score 0):

A little Googling will give you the answer here:

> It has been replaced with `stringWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error`...
>
> *Source: [What is the "stringWithContentsOfURL" replacement for objective C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039203/what-is-the-stringwithcontentsofurl-replacement-for-objective-c)*

Also, in the future, please try to spell check your inquiries.

Comment: o really i'll take a look tanks and sorry

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 NSError* error;
 NSString *string = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
```

instead. Apple shouldn't have included `stringWithContentsOfURL:` (without encoding) to start with. It has been deprecated on OS X for a long time, because that was the cause of a lot of headaches for non-English speakers.

That said, don't download something to test the connectivity. Instead, use [Reachiability](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html).

Comment: Reachability will only tell you if you have 3g or wifi connectivity, not if you can reach a site.  The best check if an address is reachable would be to implement a pinging class.  Apple has an example of this here: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/samplecode/SimplePing/Introduction/Intro.html