# Check internet connection in iPhone - not just to router

Tags: objective-c, connection, reachability

I use the normal Reachability tools to check if there is an internet connection available. It works in most cases, but if I unplug the WAN cable to the wifi-router, for some reason it still say it can find the host by wifi. If I change the web address to something that doesn't exists, it will say "The internet is down", like it should. Where is my problem?

Example:

I. I have the "internet cable" unplugged, but phone connected by wifi to router. I run with this line, the first time for this domain:

```
hostReachable = [[Reachability reachabilityWithHostName: @"www.google.com"] retain];
```

Result = No host found (correct)

II. I disable wifi in the phone. Result = Host found with WWAN (correct)

III. I enable wifi in the phone. Result = Host found with WIFI. (not correct, since router is not online)

Comment: possible duplicate  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083701/how-to-check-for-an-active-internet-connection-on-iphone-sdk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For internet checking I send an http request to one site(most probably google.com) if it does not return true, it means no internet. This case works even the connection is so slow. Here is the method.

```
- (BOOL) connectedToInternet
{
    NSString *URLString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];
return ( URLString != NULL ) ? YES : NO;
}
```

Comment: Is the "stringWithContentsOfURL is depricated"-warning something to worry about?

Comment: Am I correct if this solution wait a minute before it give the result? In that case, it's not appropriate.

Comment: You should never use deprecated code as Apple will surely decline the application.

Comment: It does not wait a minute. Why it is depracated? It works without a warning on my app.

Comment: I used something in this direction, but like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039203/what-is-the-stringwithcontentsofurl-replacement-for-objective-c

Comment: apple has changed the way of using  'encoding' to  'usedEncoding'

Comment: First of all stringWithContentsOfURL is deprecated and second this is blocking code. If your internet is DC from the router side this will give you control back somewhat after half minute sometimes. Not recommended

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083701/how-to-check-for-an-active-internet-connection-on-iphone-sdk).  The Reachability code is known to only test connectivity with your router.  There should be a notification for connectivity now.

Comment: I have followed that example. For me that would be enough, but I read somewhere that the app will not be approved in App Store if the app doesn't warn if the connection to the server disappears.