# Read Dbx File From aWebsite

Tags: iphone, xcode

I want to read Dbx file In my App from The Following site.

http://www.weather.gov/geodata/catalog/wsom/data/bp03my11.dbx

How i can do This?

Any suggestion or any Sample Source Code

Answer (score 0):

since the format of the "dbx" file is something similiar to the CSV (Comma seperated values) 
you can find the code that parses the CSV and put the pipe sign ("|") as your seperator

**The following link is the sample about the flow of line-break seperated value** 
http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-game-development/13753-tutorial-quiz-game.html#post64855

your attempt is seprating the line-break first and second seprating the | and populate it into NSArray / NSMutableArray / NSDictionary

For the url , you can access it :

```
NSError* error;
NSString* text = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:TheUrl encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error];
```

Refer to : [What is the "stringWithContentsOfURL" replacement for objective C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039203/what-is-the-stringwithcontentsofurl-replacement-for-objective-c)

or use ASIHTTPRequest to ease the steps 
http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/